# compare strings of uneven length in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, string-comparison

I have two tables. Both of them contain (dutch) postalcodes.
Those have the format 9999AA and are stored as varchar(6).
In the left table the codes are complete

```
John Smith        1234AB
Drew BarryMore    3456HR
Ted Bundy         3456TX
Henrov            8995RE
My mother         8995XX
```

In the right table the codes can be incomplete

```
1234AB Normal neigbourhood
3456   Bad neighbourhood
8995R  Very good neighbourhood
```

I need to join these tables on the postalcodes. In this example the output would have to be

```
John Smith        Normal neighbourhood
Drew BarryMore    Bad neighbourhood
Ted Bundy         Bad neighbourhood
Henrov            Very good neighbourhood
My mother         -unknown-
```

So I have to join the two tables based on the length of the postal code in the **right** table.

Any suggestions as to how to do this? I could only come up with a CASE in the ON statement but that was not so smart ;)

Comment: U are so right, I edited that. Sorry. Seems like you understood the question better than me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have no "duplicates" in the second table, you could use `like`:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.col2
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2
ON t1.postalcode LIKE t2.postalcode + '%';
```

However, this is not going to be efficient.  Instead, an index on `table2(postalcode)` and a series of `LEFT JOIN`s is probably faster:

```
SELECT t1.*, COALESCE(t2a.col2, t2b.col2, t2c.col2)
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2a ON t2a.postalcode = t1.postalcode
LEFT JOIN table2 t2b ON t2b.postalcode = LEFT(t1.postalcode, LEN(t1.postalcode) - 1)
LEFT JOIN table2 t2c ON t2c.postalcode = LEFT(t1.postalcode, LEN(t1.postalcode) - 2)
```

This can take advantage of an index on `table2(postalcode)`.  In addition, it only returns one row, even when there are multiple matches in `table2`, returning the best match.

Comment: This is how I in the end implemented it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `JOIN`.

**Query**

```
SELECT t1.col1 as name,
       coalesce(t2.col2,'-unknown-') as col2
FROM table_1 t1
LEFT JOIN table_2 t2
ON t1.pcode LIKE t2.col1 + '%';
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9e93d/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
on '1234AB' like '1234'+'%'

on firstTable.code like secondTable.code+'%'
```

In you Join search condition.

Comment: There are two different tables. For this to work I should join them first right?

Answer (score 1):

You can Use `LEFT(column,4)`

```
select t1.*, t2.col2
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on LEFT(t1.postalcode,4)=t2.postalcode
```

Comment: If the right column contains 1234A then 1234 should not be a hit, neither should 1234b be a hit. That risk is there if you only compare the first 4.